# Facebook Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, mini-site, facebook.stackoverflow

Somehow I found the [Facebook Stackoverflow](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com) site, with the icon being the regular Stack Overflow icon with a facebook icon on top of it:

> [image]

Is it an easter egg?  If so, how does it differ from the original Stack Overflow site?

Comment: @Martijn, if you feel like retagging, then [meta-tag:mini-site] seems to be a good starting point. (Either to search for more candidates for your new [meta-tag:facebook.stackoverflow], or as the tag to use instead.)

Comment: @Arjan: Use both, perhaps?

Comment: Sure, @Martijn, if you feel like it ;-) (It seems earlier, some folks used mini-site and [meta-tag:facebook].)

Comment: It's a blight on all of Stack Exchange.  You were better off not knowing...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not an easter egg; the http://facebook.stackoverflow.com site is a 'view' on stackoverflow.com, where it only shows questions that have a facebook related tag. In essence, it is the same underlying database, but the question lists are filtered.

From the [site's FAQ](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq):

> Questions asked on Stack Overflow with facebook related tags. If you want your question to appear here, it must have one of those tags.

The FAQ lists the full set of tags used to create the filter.

The site was created by Facebook in collaboration with Stack Overflow ([Facebook's announcement](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/545/), [StackOverflow announcement](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/)) to support Facebook Platform developers. When you visit the site without logging in, you are greeted with a message box telling you about the site:

[image: facebook.stackoverflow.com greeting]

Comment: Wow, is it some kind of developer advertisement facebook is doing?

Comment: I've found the facebook announcement and added it to the answer. In short: yes, this is a facebook-sponsored site.

Comment: Also [announced on the SE blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/).

Comment: @Arjan: thanks, I'll add that to the answer if you don't mind.