# Why the sudden influx of Facebook questions on Meta all of a sudden?

Tags: discussion, questions, meta, facebook

How come there are so many Facebook-related questions here on the Meta site in the last few hours? Did something happen that I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone asked this question: [Facebook Stackoverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147208/187824) . And Martijn Pieters answered his/her question. Then he edited the tag 'facebook-stackoverflow' in all facebook related questions. Thats the reason.

Comment: Ah, that was it. Thanks. I thought maybe I was missing something, that somehow I had managed to put Meta in Facebook-mode or something.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it was just a series of edits on older questions that were tagged [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) today.

Do you have any examples of *recent* Facebook-related questions that somehow made it to MSO?

Comment: No, only the one hims056 pointed out was actually new. So it's OK.

Comment: The exact tag was `facebook.stackexchange`. :-)