# What's the difference between facebook.stackoverflow.com and stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, facebook

What is the difference between [facebook.stackoverflow.com](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com) and [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) aside from the subdomain and the other title?

Both pages are using the same questions and the same user profiles/information.

On facebook.stackoverflow.com I can also see my questions not related to facebook:
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12567518/how-to-handle-dynamically-loaded-managed-libraries-in-c-sharp

When I set my favorite tags to some facebook tags and nothing else then is the only difference the title, the icon and the subdomain, or are there notable special features on facebook.stackoverflow.com?

Comment: Have you read [the FAQ](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/faq)? It's basically a filtered view of SO focusing on Facebook-related tags only.

Comment: in the review queue, there are questions tagged facebook with comments saying "this is offtopic: ask on facebook.stackoverflow.com" - are those comments just wrong?

Comment: afaik it is possible to ask facebook related questions on stackoverflow and it is also possible to ask facebook unrelated questions on facebook.stackoverflow

Comment: @KateGregory: yes, I'm pretty sure they are wrong.

Comment: You can read all about it in this blog post: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/

Comment: @Paedow true, but on that "sub domain" there are added tweaks and tricks like taking your Facebook profile picture.

Comment: And the other side's blog - https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/545/

Comment: @Lix cool, wasn't aware that Stack Overflow replaced Facebook's [forums](http://www.facebookforum.co.uk/) which are now nothing more than spam container... :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd when i first registered on stackoverflow (approx. 2 months ago) my profile picture automatically synched with my facebook photo, so that´s not only on facebook.SO but the blog entry is very interesting and the entry from facebook itself complains it.

Comment: @Paedow yeah, that's because you were using your Facebook account. Anyway, there **are** benefits in that site see the blog post..

Comment: ok, but really now there isn´t any difference xecept of the different settings and some visual stuff

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Stackoverflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147208/facebook-stackoverflow)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The FSO filter only displays questions containing one of the Facebook related tags.

Comment: but this is only on the first page

Comment: The logo is also slightly different :)

Comment: yes but this is no difference

Comment: @pae nope... Its the same on all internal pages too... If you have any evidence that this is not the case, please post it with some examples...