# Facebook Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

Can someone explain to me what [Facebook Stack Overflow](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com) represents?

This is very similar to the original Stack Overflow site!

Comment: this is partnership between facebook and stackvoerflow and i think this is one way so is earning money http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/facebook-stackoverflow/

Comment: It is basically only a particular view of Stack Overflow. You're still on the exact same site with the exact same content. Just filtered based on Facebook related tags.

Comment: @NullPonyPointer Thanks, I read the blog post. This is an interesting feature for the site.

Comment: There should be so for all tags. :P

Comment: As much as the answer below is an exact copy of the first paragraph of the answer in that dupe. =)

Comment: @J.Steen, i agree, see my updated answer.

Comment: @J.Steen Oops, That wasn't my fault :D

Comment: @DKN Of course not.

Comment: @Raynold Rather than answer with a copied answer, you should have flagged this question as a dupe. I believe that is supposed standard procedure, but SE is community driven so "decisions" about "policy" change all the time, and I'm not quite sure how it works on the metas where giving help is paramount. =)

Comment: @J.Steen , next time i will keep this thing in my mind, thanks for this information.

Comment: A specific subsection where we get a lot of low quality contributions, and a promise from Facebook staff to contribute to but never came through on.

Comment: @kiamlaluno could you try to edit in smaller batches?  You mostly flushed the front page of MSE today.  I appreciate the enthusiasm, but spreading them out a little helps make sure that people who posted shortly before your wave of edits get some attention too.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Original Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147209/214722)

The http://facebook.stackoverflow.com site is a 'view' on stackoverflow.com, where it only shows questions that have a facebook related tag. In essence, it is the same underlying database, but the question lists are filtered.